# Cordova/PhoneGap plugin to track app installs from a Facebook mobile app install campaign

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am working on cordova app and I am looking into options to track app installs from a Facebook mobile app install campaign. The phonegap-facebook-plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) looks promising but other than a claim that app activations are automatically tracked, I am not sure how to proceed. I assume that there is more to it than simply dropping in the plugin, I must have to initialize something somewhere, I would think.

In addition, I am looking for guidance on how to test this before deploying.

I would love to hear specifics from anyone who has solved this problem, either with this plugin or through some other means.

Comment: Did you manage to progress with this at all?